# htaccess rewrite " " with "-"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^error$ error.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ game.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /error [L,R=301]
```

How can make it to work for example:

`localhost/Test1%20Test2 or localhost/Test1 Test2`

to work with

```
localhost/test1-test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule s your **very first rule**:

```
RewriteRule "^([^ ]*) +([^ ]* .*)$" /$1-$2 [L]
RewriteRule "^([^ ]*) ([^ ]*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Can you provide details? What URL did you try to test it and what eror you get?